# Devices are invalid in File Manager

Tags: raspbian, usb

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian

I have 2 questions related to not valid drives in File Manager.

Question 1,

I have a device in File Manager menu GO->DEVICES Y032V. This device when clicked always returns an error message “The specified directory 'computer:///Y032V.drive' is not valid”
Even if I disconnect everything of the Pi, only power supply is connected, the device is there.
**What device is that?** Maybe the SD card itself? But invalid?

Question 2,

I attached a USB SSD as the main storage.

Option 1
After system boot up the Raspbian GUI auto mounts the SSD to /media/pi. I made the mount folder accessible to all my users.
In File Manager menu GO->DEVICES I can see the SSD and when I click on it it takes me to the mounting point.
It works well.

Option 2
I tried to follow the RaspberryPi website recommendation https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/external-storage.md
and I created a folder /mnt/mySSD and made it read-write accessible to all my users. In /etc/fstab I mounted the SSD to this folder. Users can read and write. It works well.

But when I open the File Manager and go to the menu GO -> DEVICES  mySSD I get an error message “The specified directory 'computer:///Samsung%20Portable%20SSD%20T5.drive' is not valid”
Why is that?
**Is is safe to use it this way (option 2)?**

Comment: Sounds like a network drive. `computer:///Y032V.drive`

Comment: And BTW, please ask only one question. You've asked 2 question.